# VSCode Typescript helper ignoring `exclude` field present in `tsconfig.json`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vite, vitest

I have setup vite and vitest on my project, and have set the following settings on `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "types": [
            "vite/client",
            "vite-plugin-svgr/client",
            "node",
            "vitest/globals",
            "@testing-library/jest-dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": ["src", "types", "vitest.ts"],
    "exclude": ["**/*.test.tsx", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

However, vscode chooses to ignore the excluded test files and throws the following error.
[image]

I either want vscode to stop warning me on test files itself, or take my config including all globals. How do I do this?

Note: I have added the following in my `settings.json`

```
    "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude Are there any included files that are importing the files you want to exclude? Or in any way depending upon them?

Comment: So the test files itself ignore the typescript errors, but vscode does not.